# In Rest-Assured query using date only without using the exact date time

Tags: java, rest-assured

In sys_created_on field ,I tried to search using wild card as suffix or prefix with just the  date but no result came, unless I gave the exact date time , so is there anyway to  give start_time=2023-09-02 05 and search? What I want is a partial search using date since I don't know the exact time.

. In some APIs, wildcard searches are not allowed by design for various reasons, I think it might be the case here as well.

```
 @Test()
    public void getStatus(){
        String tableName = "Mytable";
         String tagValue = "Mytag";


        RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().basic("username", "password");

        // Search for a record with the specified tag value
        Response response = request.given()
                .queryParam("Tags", tagValue).queryParam("start_time", "2023-09-02 05:00:01")
                .get("https://helloworld.com/api/now/table/" + tableName);

        // Check if the response is successful
       response.then().statusCode(200);
   
  
        JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
        String actualExecutionStatus = jsonPathEvaluator.get("result.status[0]");
        String actualsys_created_on = jsonPathEvaluator.get("result.sys_created_on[0]");
        System.out.println("actualExecutionStatus =="+actualExecutionStatus);
        System.out.println("actualsys_created_on =="+actualsys_created_on);
        System.out.println("response body=="+response.getBody().asString());

    }
```

Comment: It depends on api of `helloworld.com`, nothing relates to Rest-assured.

Comment: Yes managed to solve by using String startDate = "2023-09-02"; Then pass the key and value as below. Key was sysparm_query and value was appended with LIKE.

.queryParam("sysparm_query", "start_timeLIKE"+startDate) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, don’t understand your question.